# Finding the mean of $Y=X_1+\cdots+X_N$ where $N$ is Poisson and $X_i$ Bernoulli

Tags: probability-theory

We have a random variable $N$ that follows the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ and $Y=\sum_{i=1}^N X_i $, where $X_i$ follows the Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\rho$ and $(X_i)$ are independent variables. We don't know whether $N$ and $(X_i)$ are independent.

I want to find the mean of $Y$. So I give this solution and I want to know if it is correct: We know that $E(Y)=E(E(Y\mid N))$, but for a given $x$, $Y\mid N=x $ has binomial distribution with parameters $x$ and $\rho$ so $E(Y\mid N=x)=x\rho$. Then $E(Y\mid N)=Nρ$, so $E(Y)=E(Y\rho)=\rho Ε(Y)$ and $Y$ has the Poisson distribution, hence $E(Y)=\lambda$. Finally $E(Y)=\rho\lambda$.

If that solution is correct, I find it strange that if $N$ and $(X_i)$ are independent we have the same result.

Comment: i dont know how , i am sorry.

Comment: "for given $x$, $Y\mid X=x$ has Binomial distribution with parameters $x$ and $\rho$": can you justify that even if $X$ and $(X_i)_i$ are not independent?

Comment: You can learn. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I think / we usually use $Y\mid X$ to show a conditional distribution, since $Y/X$ is taken to be division. I know this is not universal, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: @Jack : "LaTeX" is a misnomer that may confuse people.  If someone masters MathJax (which is what this is) and thinks this is LaTeX, then encounters actual LaTeX, it may be something of a shock to them to learn that LaTeX is something other than this and they don't know LaTeX. $\qquad$

Comment: I'd start by thinking about $\operatorname{E}(X_1\mid N=n)$.  If it is equal to $\rho$ regardless of the value of $n$, then I think you're just about done.  Otherwise, there may be complications. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy but without any type of assumption (the simplest being independence), there *can* be complications. We could have $X_1$ following two different distributions according to whether $N$ is even or odd, for instance (but still having a Bernoulli$(\rho)$ marginal).

Comment: Can you clarify that $X$ is the vector of $X=(X_i)$?

Comment: @ClementC. : Exactly.  That's the kind of thing I meant by "there may be complications". Although I'm not sure that alters the marginal expected value of the sum. $\qquad$

Comment: @yo' No: before the edits, $X$ denoted what is now called $N$ (the Poisson r.v.)

Comment: @ClementC. Ah ok, makes sense. I might have made some mess myself when re-formatting (I think not, but it was strange that some $X$ were Chi's), if that's the case, I'm sorry.

Comment: @ClementC.can you justify that even if XX and (Xi)i(Xi)i are not independent                                                                                                               hmm  probably not, that's might be the wrong..

Comment: @probablyme thanks!

Comment: @EvansS.  Since $P(N)=\frac{\lambda^{N} e^{-\lambda}}{N!}, N=0,1,2,\ldots$  , what'll be $Y$ if $N=0$?

Comment: we consider that Y=0 if N=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Individually, $X_i$ are Bernoulli distributed. However when calculating $E[Y|N]$, you cannot conclude that $Y$ is just binomially distributed since $X_i$ and $N$ are not independent. As an example, let $N=1$ if $X_1=0$ and $N=2$ when $X_1=1$. Then $E[Y|N=1]=0$, $E[Y|N=2]=3/2$, but

$$E[Y]=(3/2)P(N=2)=3/4\neq 1,$$

where $1$ is the expectation of $X_1+X_2$.

Comment: you mean that Xi have Bernulli  distribution with parameter 1/2, right?

Comment: the example is that E[Y/N=2] =3/2 but if Y/N=2 had the Binormal distribution with parameter 2 and 1/2 then E[Y/N=2] = 1 , so that's prove that Y/N=2 doesnt follow binomal distribution., am i getting something wrong?

Comment: Yea that's the point: $Y|N$ is not binomially distributed.

Comment: thank you!! One more question because i am not really sure , how did you calculate the E[Y/N=2] . This equals to Σ y P(Y=y,N=2)/P(N=2) but how did you calculate P(Y=y,N=2) ?

Comment: @EvansS. $E[Y|N=2]=E[1+X_2]=1+E[X_2]=3/2$

Comment: i think i understood , thanks!